# Как вынести скрипт из элемента в шапку сайта?

Tags: javascript

Вот есть инпут, в нем прописан скрипт... слышал, что лучше скрипты выносить в шапку страницы. Но я не знаю синтаксиса js, и не знаю что писать...

```
<input type="text" class="phone-input" value="+7" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == 0 || this.value.length == 1) this.value = '+7'">
```

Вряд ли что могу написать

```
<script>

</script>
```

а как внутри писать чтоб все работало, не знаю, не просто же скопировать
Подскажите как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Код js лучше выносить не в шапку, а отдельный файлик c расширением js, который подключается на html старнице. Примерно так это выглядит на jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('input.phone-input').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value.length == 0 || this.value.length == 1) this.value = '+7';
  })
});
```

Comment: инпут уже будет выглядеть так <input type="text" class="phone-input" value="+7">

Answer (score 1):

Напишите отдельный файл скриптов (допустим, scripts.js).

В нем у вас будут методы типа

```
function InputHandler(){
    if (this.value.length == 0 || this.value.length == 1) this.value = '+7';
});
```

Соответственно, в HTML:

```
<script src="/<папка_где_лежат_скрипты>/scripts.js" />
...
<input type="text" class="phone-input" value="+7" onkeyup="InputHandler()">
```

Основная мораль всего этого: править код в одном месте всегда проще и быстрее, чем js-функции, размазанные по html-разметке.